# Autocomplete and Axios

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I try to create an autocomplete form with axios, and I can't find the way to share data between rails and my form

here is my form :

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" onkeyup="valueChange(this);">
        <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript :

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
        var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, null);
    });

    function valueChange(elem) {
        var instance = M.Autocomplete.getInstance(elem);

        console.log("search for " + elem.value);
        axios.post("<%= test_autocomplete_search_path %>", {
            search: elem.value,
            authenticity_token: '<%= form_authenticity_token %>',
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                instance.updateData(response.data.nom_commune);
                console.log(response.data.nom_commune);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert(error);
            });
    };
</script>
```

Here is my ruby :

```
def autocomplete_search
    towns = Town.select(:nom_commune).where("nom_commune ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
    render :json => towns.map  { |town| {
        name: town.nom_commune,
        placeholder: nil
      }
    }
```

the problem is autocomplete except elements formated in this way :

```
data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
```

and I have it formated in 'json' way
I don't want to loop and waste cpu time to change then, is their a fancy way to 1/ push properly for server OR 2/ get it properly in client side ?

thanks

greg

Comment: My need would be to transform a Ror json list to javascript :

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
        var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {});
    });

    function valueChange(elem) {
        var instance = M.Autocomplete.getInstance(elem);

        console.log("search for " + elem.value);
        axios.post("<%= test_autocomplete_search_path %>", {
            search: elem.value,
            authenticity_token: '<%= form_authenticity_token %>',
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            var map = new Object();
            for (bcl = 0; bcl < response.data.length; bcl ++) {
                map[response.data[bcl].town] = null;
            }
            if (response.data.length > 0) {
                console.log(map);
                instance.updateData(map);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    };
</script>
```